# Room database not generating code for delete and update annotation

Tags: android-room

Using 2.5.1 Room version

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1"
```

While compiling code is not getting generated for the @Delete and @Update annotations. Is there any logs printed for code generation? Can't find any error

Comment: What error do you get? Provide also please the code you've written so far

Comment: error: AssetStatusDao_Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract method delete(List<? extends AssetStatus>,Continuation<? super Integer>) in ReadWriteDao
public final class AssetStatusDao_Impl extends AssetStatusDao {
Basically delete method is not generated.

Comment: Moving from kapt to ksp did generate the proper code for Dao but it has issue with @Ignore in Entity class.

Answer (score 0):

For the newer versions, you should use this room database dependency.
`    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1"
ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.5.1'
This goes in the data package

  @Database(entities = [InventorySchedule::class], version =1)
    abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun inventoryScheduleDao() : InventoryScheduleDao
    companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null
    fun getDatabase(context: Context) : AppDatabase {
    return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this){
    Room.databaseBuilder(
    context,
    AppDatabase::class.java,
    "app_database")
     .createFromAsset("tnventory_database.db")
     .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
     .build()
     .also{
     INSTANCE = it}
     }
     }
     }
This as well
 @Entity(tableName = "Inventory")
    data class InventorySchedule(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    @NotNull
    @ColumnInfo (name = "item_type") val itemType: String,
    @NotNull
    @ColumnInfo (name = "item_quantity") val itemQuantity: Int)

    This interface goes into the same file data, 
    @Dao
    interface InventoryScheduleDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY size ASC")
    fun getAll(): Flow<List<Inventory>>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE size = :size ORDER BY 
    price ASC")
    fun getByPrice(size:String): Flow<List<InventorySchedule>>}
    Also, you would need this in the UI to start the methods.
    class InventoryScheduleViewModel(private val 
    inventoryScheduleDao: InventoryScheduleDao):     ViewModel() 
    {
    // Get example item
    fun getFullSchedule(): Flow<List<InventorySchedule>> = 
    InventoryScheduleDao.getAll()
    // Get example item by size
    fun getScheduleFor(size: String): 
    Flow<List<InventorySchedule>> =   
    inventoryScheduleDao.getByPrice(size)
    companion object {
    val factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
    initializer {
    val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as 
    InventoryScheduleApplication)


InventoryScheduleViewModel(application.
   database.busScheduleDao())
   }
   }
   }
   }
This goes into example file
class InventoryScheduleApplication : Application() {
val database: AppDatabase by lazy { 
AppDatabase.getDatabase(this)}
}
```

> another possible case for the dao file would be@Daointerface ItemDao {@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)suspend fun insert(item: Item)@Updatesuspend fun update(item: Item)@Delete
> suspend fun delete(item: Item)@Query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = :id")fun getItem(id: Int): Flow<Item?>@Query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY name ASC")fun getAllItems(): Flow<List>}

> - Repository that provides insert, update, delete, and retrieve of [Item] from a given data source.*/interface ItemsRepository{fun getAllItemsStream() : Flow<List>fun getItemStream(id: Int) : Flow<Item?>suspend fun insertItem(item: Item)suspend fun deleteItem(item: Item)suspend fun updateItem(item: Item)}